# spring security permit static assets not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I understand `@EnableWebSecurity` disables all spring security defaults, therefore I have overridden the required methods in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. However, no matter what I do css and all other static assets get a 403 or 405.

Using spring boot 2.0.0.M7 with spring security created from https://start.spring.io/

Folder structure is the normal

```
- resources
   - static
      - css
          styles.css
```

`web.ignoring()` doesn't do anything for some reason, yet when I enable debugging it does mention that the below paths have been bypassed but I still get a 405.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/webjars/**");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.
            authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
     }
```

}

For further debugging I have even tried to permit everything by doing the below, but every url is still denied which is extremely confusing and makes me think there is some key concept I am not grasping.

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
```

Finally, I have also tried to implement `WebMvcConfigurer` with various combinations of locations which don't work either.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/webjars/");
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the above security configuration is actually correct. You don't have to implement `WebMvcConfigurer`, only extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Turns out to be a **very hard** bug to track down. I had a controller that served up a registration form like this.

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String getRegisterView(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("registerDto", new RegisterDto());
        return "register";
    }

    @PostMapping 
    public String register(@Valid @ModelAttribute("registerDto") RegisterDto registerDto, BindingResult result) {
        // business logic...
        return "register";
    }
}
```

The bug is the in the `@PostMapping` where I forgot to include the path!! which causes spring all sorts of issues when mapping paths. It would be nice if these annotations threw exceptions if no path was provided.

To fix this I updated it to `@PostMapping("/register")` and now all paths inside

`web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/webjars/**");` are allowed through.

So ensure all your contoller route annotations have paths in them!

Comment: That's why you got 405 - method not allowed - the get request was routed to a post mapping :-)